# How to disable beeps if there is no audio driver installed

Tags: windows-xp

Its really irritating in windows xp if you haven't yet installed an audio driver. The motherboard beeps at times. I've already disabled the system speaker in the devmgmt.msc. But it still beeps. What do I do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using Win7, but the wording should be the same:

- In Device Management, go View > Show hidden devices (ensure it is checked).
- That will show a device category called "Non-plug and Play Drivers".
- Find the "Beep" driver, and disable it.

Beep should be able to be disabled safely. You may have to reboot for it to take effect.